# Use of await with Modal Controller in ionic 6

Tags: ionic-framework

[Official docs example](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal) shows the await use as

```
return await modal.present();
```

and then getting the data back as

```
const { data } = await modal.onWillDismiss();
```

However, above didn't work for me, specially when getting the data back. I get error `onWillDismiss' does not exist on type 'Promise<HTMLIonModalElement>'`. The same happened for `onDidDismiss` for me.

Following works for me, I have to use `await (await modal).`. Am i missing something here or doing something totally wrong?

```
async presentModal(){
    let modal = this.modalCntrl.create({
                    component: CreateTestModalComponent,
                    componentProps: { selectedName: this.name }, //gets passed in as the INPUT property
                    keyboardClose: true,
                    swipeToClose: true
                  });
    await (await modal).present();

    const { data, role } = await (await modal).onWillDismiss(); //onDidDismiss()
    if(role === "confirm"){
      this.presentAlert(`Message passed back<br/><br/>${data.message}<br/><br/>Role '${role}' passed back`);
    }
    else{
      this.presentAlert(`Cancel clicked!<br/><br/>Role '${role}' passed back`);
    }
  }

  

async presentAlert(message: string){
    const alert = await this.alertCntrl.create({
      header: 'Alert',
      message: message,
      buttons: ['Ok']
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
```

I would like to clarify one more thing, there is a lag in alert display. When using `onWillDismiss()` the alert displays much faster/earlier than `onDidDismiss()`.

I am new to ionic 6 and learning right now, hence above questions/confusions.

Node: v14.15.5
npm: v6.14.11
ng: v11.2.0
ionic: v6.13.1

Comment: Ur problem is here : await (await modal) just no need to do an await for the await since it will always cause an error, just do await modal.present(); or await modal.onWillDismiss();

Comment: That is the same thing i am pointing out as well. Docs also say to use `await modal.present();` and `await modal.onWillDismiss();`. When using this i get an error. The only way i can get rid of the error is to use `const { data, role } = await (await modal).onWillDismiss();`.

Comment: Ok the begining of the statement is wrong, let modal =this.modal... is wrong , i'll write the answer below

Comment: Yup, you are correct, it should be `let modal = await this.modalCntrl.create(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async presentModal(){
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({keep ur props the same..});
    modal.present();
    // now here there should be no errors from above side after we put aeait before modal create
    const { data, role } = await modal.onWillDismiss();
    if(role === "confirm"){
      this.presentAlert(`Message passed back<br/><br/>${data.message}<br/><br/>Role '${role}' passed back`);
    }
    else{
      this.presentAlert(`Cancel clicked!<br/><br/>Role '${role}' passed back`);
    }
}
```